# C# MongoDB - Read one record from database and write it to stream

Tags: c#, mongodb

I'm trying to return all records from my database. This collection is comparably big (250MB), so I can't load it in the memory. My idea is to load every record individually and write it to the `NetworkStream`.

**My problem:**

The client closes connection after `await writer.WriteLineAsync();`
(I tried to leave this line away but didn't work)

**My Code:**

```cs
var writer = new StreamWriter(stream, null, -1, true);
await writer.WriteLineAsync($"HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
await writer.WriteLineAsync($"Content-Type: application/json charset-utf8");
await writer.WriteLineAsync($"Transfer-Encoding: chunked");
await writer.WriteLineAsync();

using (var cursor = await collection.FindAsync(new BsonDocument()))
{
    while (await cursor.MoveNextAsync())
    {
        var batch = cursor.Current;
        foreach (var document in batch)
        {
            byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(document.ToString());
            await stream.WriteAsync(data, 0, data.Length);
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for helping!

Comment: Also it would be interesting to know, how to write the code, so that the client receives a file. I tried something like: "await writer.WriteLineAsync("Content-Type: application/octet-stream"); "

Comment: `The client closes connection after await writer.WriteLineAsync();`

how MongoClient is related to this writer?

Comment: The writer is coming from a NetworkStream.

Comment: I solved it, the point was to return a Task from the function where this code was embedded in.